# How do I install MegaTunix? 

Tags: 11.10, installation

I am attempting to install MegaTunix onto a laptop that I can plug into my car's ECU to monitor and tweek the car's performance. I downloaded the Megatunix.deb file and opened it in Software Center. It says that libgtkglext1 is a missing dependancy and will not allow the install to proceed.

I have 11.10 (i386) installed. Should I try an older version (eg. 10.04 LTS) or is there a way to satisfy the dependancy issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libgtkglext1) to install libgtkglext1.
When it opens the Software Center, does it show it as installed or not? If not, install this package and try installing MegaTunix from the .deb archive again.

Comment: Thanks @Agmenor, your link worked and Megatunix works well too!

Comment: If this answer or any future one helped you, please consider upvoting it and/or accepting it as the right answer.